How can I use MapMyIndia in Kotlin with Jetpack compose?
I've been trying to integrate MapMyIndia with jetpack compose but so far I have found nothing on how to use it for Turn-By-Turn navigation.
I have searched over the internet for references to MapMyIndia and Jetpack Compose but I have not found any article that has been able to help me.

Mappls (MapMyIndia) doesn't provide any Jetpack Compose version, Anyway, you can Implement the Map section (or screen) of your app using XML, and the rest with Compose.

is there a tutorial on how to use views with compose?

Check #1 and #2

For anyone who is looking for the specific code:
@Composable
fun MapComponent(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val lifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current

    MapplsAccountManager.getInstance().restAPIKey = "key"
    MapplsAccountManager.getInstance().mapSDKKey = "key"
    MapplsAccountManager.getInstance().atlasClientId = "client id"
    MapplsAccountManager.getInstance().atlasClientSecret = "secret"
    Mappls.getInstance(LocalContext.current)

    val mapView = remember { MapView(context).apply { onCreate(null) } }

    // Manage the lifecycle of the MapView
    DisposableEffect(lifecycleOwner) {
        val observer = LifecycleEventObserver { _, event ->
            when (event) {
                Lifecycle.Event.ON_START -> mapView.onStart()
                Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME -> mapView.onResume()
                Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE -> mapView.onPause()
                Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP -> mapView.onStop()
                Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY -> mapView.onDestroy()
                else -> {}
            }
        }

        // Add observer to the lifecycle
        lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.addObserver(observer)

        // Cleanup when the effect leaves the composition
        onDispose {
            lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.removeObserver(observer)
            mapView.onDestroy()  // Proper cleanup of the MapView
        }
    }

    // AndroidView to display the MapView
    AndroidView(
        factory = { mapView },
        modifier = modifier
    )
}


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?

If it uses a View, you should be able to convert it to an AndroidView Composable.
https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/compose/migrate/interoperability-apis/views-in-compose
